# Get total size of Recycle Bin

Tags: powershell, batch-file, wmi

I have a need and have not been able to find any question related to what I intend to achieve. I am trying to get a script (either PowerShell or DOS WMI) to get total size of recycle bin but where there are more than one drive.

I have tried using this command line `DIR /S %SYSTEMDRIVE%\$RECYCLE.BIN | FINDSTR /C:File(s)` but this only shows me size of recycle bin usage on the C: drive but I need to also get size for other drives on each servers irrespective of the drive letters used.

I have checked Script Guy but couldn't find any close to it.

Comment: I think the answer by @ArchGriffin will give you everything you need to get started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689023/deleting-contents-of-w2k3-recycle-bin

Comment: Taking a look at it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the "Get-RecycleBinSize" script from http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-RecycleBinSize-092f15c7

It's fantastic. I've tested it against 2003, 2008, 2008 R2 and 2012. It returns an object for each recycle bin (i.e. by drive, and user account). An example:

```
Get-RecycleBinSize -ComputerName server01

Computer : server01
Drive    : C:
User     : Domain\username
BinSID   : S-1-5-21-1231231234-1231231234-1231231234-12345
Size     : 20
```

The returned size is in KB so you might want to do some formatting on this.

Whilst using it for reporting purposes, I've also incorporated it into a script that emails users when their recycle bin is over a certain size to ask them to empty it. You can however can forcefully empty it with the -empty parameter.

To get the total space used by the server you could run the following:

```
Get-RecycleBinSize -ComputerName server01 | % { $totalspace = $totalspace + [System.Math]::Round($_.Size/1MB,0) }
$totalspace
```

Comment: The technical ability to "control" is not equal to procedural practice. Besides, it's irrelevant to this question. I was giving an example of how it *could* be extended further. This solution uses PowerShell and doesn't require explicitly defined shell objects. If you think the script can be improved by using them, please feel free to contact the author on the technet page. Regards, Robin

Comment: @Rob this was one of the first few scripts I tried but it does not run. No error no output on screen. Did you test using DOS or PowerShell console?

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover I ran this directly from within the PowerShell console. You could call PowerShell and the script from within DOS but I wouldn't recommend it if you can avoid it. How are you trying to run it?

Comment: Tried .\Get-RecycleBinSize -ComputerName xxx, Get-RecycleBinSize -ComputerName xxx from powershell

Comment: It's actually just a function and not a full script which is why that isn't working. Try copying and pasting the contents of that PS1 file into your PowerShell console. Then just type `Get-RecycleBinSize -ComputerName xxx` without the ".\" part. Does that work for you? It does for me. If you want to turn it into a script that's a bit of additional work.

Comment: I copied the content of the script into PowerShell console but it stops at:>>   #Resetting ErrorActionPref
>>   $ErrorActionPreference = $TempErrAct
>>  }#End End
>> }#End Function

Comment: OK I figured it out by starting with . .\Get-RecycleBinSize.ps1 i.e with space between the dots and then ran the command